# Overflow menu gone after Firefox-ESR update?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, user-interface

Instead of the overflow menu that drops down and lets me choose which addons I want in it, it just shows an addon icon and lists all my addons.

I have about 25 addons, most of which I don't need to interact with. so a list of all of them makes them more cumbersome to use.

How do I get the overflow menu back to the way it was before? Or do I just have to just downgrade to an older version of Firefox?

I'm using Firefox-ESR on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

For better or worse, this is the questionable new UI design that Mozilla's Firefox developers and management chose.  Many people, including myself, think it's a big mistake.  The best place to express your opinion is by following the links on [this Mozilla page](https://www.mozilla.org/about/forums/).

You can downgrade if you like, but that adds security risks, so I don't recommend it.  You are better off waiting until the next ESR release, which improves the native functionality of that menu a little bit.  Or, you can switch to the general release now, which will have the same benefit.

You can also write CSS code and apply it using the amazingly powerful `userChrome.css` feature present only in Firefox (one of Firefox's standout features).  Because of how Mozilla changed the upstream code, you can't use CSS to get it back exactly how you had things before, but you can certainly significantly improve on Mozilla's current design (which I have done).